# Attribute Error: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' when make word bag from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

here's my dataframe `l2_name`

```
    l2_name
0   Camp Site
1   Theme Park
2   Beach
3   others
4   Domestic Airport
```

Here's what I try

```
l2 = [set(x.split()) for x in l2_name['l2_name'].str.lower()]
```

Error message

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-5de5cc938292> in <module>
----> 1 l2 = [set(x.split()) for x in l2_name['l2_name'].str.lower()]

<ipython-input-23-5de5cc938292> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 l2 = [set(x.split()) for x in l2_name['l2_name'].str.lower()]

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

What's wrong, the code works on other dataframe

Comment: What's the datatype of the `l2_name` column? If the datatype is 'object` it might be both strings and floats and that might be because there's a `NaN` in there, which is considered as a `float` which might cause this error. You can try to run `l2_name = l2_name.dropna()`

Comment: You can do `for x in l2_name['l2_name']: try: x.split() except: print x` to see rows where it's causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

If there are strings and misisng values you can remove them before converting to lowercase:

```
l2 = [set(x.split()) for x in l2_name['l2_name'].dropna().str.lower()]
```

If possible some numbers in data and `str.lower` convert them to `NaN`s remove values after:

```
l2 = [set(x.split()) for x in l2_name['l2_name'].str.lower().dropna()]
```

Another solution:

```
l2 = l2_name['l2_name'].str.lower().dropna().str.split().apply(set).tolist()
```